# iOS - Make only subview clickable

Tags: ios, objective-c, dialog, subview, clickable

I am trying to make a custom dialog view. I have come pretty far, however there is one issue. When my dialog has popped up, I can press on textfields behind it. How can I make sure that the user can only click on the subview that is the dialog view when it is present?

Comment: disable the userInteraction for another views, enable the interaction in your dialog view only.

Comment: is there no better solution than disabling all other views separately? Can't I just disable everything in the containing view and just enable the one subview somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution: when you show dialog create view

```
 CGRect viewBackFrame =  (CGRect){
        .origin = CGPointZero,
        .size = parentView.frame.size
    };
 UIView* viewBack = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:viewBackFrame];
 viewBack.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
 [parent insertSubview:viewBack belowSubview:dialog];
```

Answer (score 1):

UIView has a property called exclusiveTouch that is supposed to do what you are trying to achieve. Setting your dialog's exclusiveTouch property to YES should do the trick.

Link to [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/exclusiveTouch)